# Usage of numpy.ufunc.identity

Tags: python, numpy

I wonder what line `r = ufct.identity` does inside function `ufunc_reduce`. Does it just initialize the operation exactly like `r = 0`?

```
a = np.array([2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([8,5,4])
c = np.array([5,4,6,8,3])

def ufunc_reduce(ufct, *vectors):
    vs = np.ix_(*vectors)
    r = ufct.identity
    for v in vs:
        r = ufct(r,v)
    return r

ufunc_reduce(np.add,a,b,c)
```

Comment: The `identity` attribute is used in the regular `ufunc.reduce` as wll, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, for the ufunc `np.add`, `ufct.identity` is `0`. But for another function it may be something else. For instance, `np.multiply.identity` is `1`.

The `ufunc_reduce` function you show doesn't know in advance what function it will be given, so it can't be hard-coded to use either `0` or `1`. It gets the proper value by checking the `identity` attribute of the ufunc instead.